# Exception when importing hashids in typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, tsconfig, hashids

I'm trying to import `hashids` in Typescript:

You can clone the code from [here](https://github.com/cstffx/hashids-example.git)

==========  index.ts ==========

```js
import Hashids from "hashids";
const encoder = new Hashids();
```

But I get the next error:

=========== Console =========

```sh
export { Hashids as default };
^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:895:18)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:995:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:815:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:727:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:852:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/persona-service/src/Example.ts:1:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:959:30)
    at Module.m._compile (/var/www/persona-service/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:814:23)
    at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:995:10)
```

This is my `tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "incremental": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "module": "CommonJS",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "types": [
      "node",
      "express",
      "hashids"
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

I'm also using `nodemon` with this config:

```
{
  "watch" : ["src"],
  "ext": "ts",
  "exec": "ts-node ./src/index.ts"
}
```

What can be happening here?

Comment: googling didn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checking the git repo for the hashids package found an issue relating to import for certain node versions:

[hashids issue on the repo](https://github.com/niieani/hashids.js/issues/210)

A workaround mentioned there is to use require instead of import

```
const Hashids = require('hashids/cjs');
```

I hope this gets you back on track.